# How to off sound background when video played di as3

Tags: actionscript-3, video

I have a sound background in my application. This is the code in frame 1

```
var music:Sound;
var trans:SoundTransform;
var channel:SoundChannel;
var musicOn:Boolean = false;


music=new Sound(new URLRequest("src/lonely.mp3"));
trans=new SoundTransform(1,-1);
channel= music.play(0, 1000, trans);
play_btn.visible = false;


play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onSound);
stop_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,offSound);

   function offSound(e:Event) {
      musicOn = false;
      play_btn.visible = true;
      stop_btn.visible = false;
      trans.volume=0;
      SoundMixer.soundTransform = trans;
      }

  function onSound(e:Event) {
      musicOn = true;
      play_btn.visible = false;
      stop_btn.visible = true;
      trans.volume=.3;
      SoundMixer.soundTransform = trans;
      }
```

In frame 210, I embedded file video. But, when my video played the sound background still playing, and when I stop the sound of background, my sound in video also stop playing. How to stop just background sound without stop the sound of video?
Thank You...

Answer (score 0):

Change the volume of your sound with the `soundTransform` property of your `channel`

`channel = music.play(0, 1000, trans);`

change the volume with:

`channel.soundTransform = new SoundTransform('Your volume here', 0);`

change `'Your volume here'` with 0 or anything from ranges 0-1